# Excel list of ranges lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, formula, vlookup

Sorry, but I'm a novice - I have a list of number ranges and then a number input such as below.

1-2  A
2-3  B
3-4  C

So when I have an input of 3.5, I want it to present me with C. I can't figure out a way to do this without having to do several different IF statements and a lot of 'less thans'. I tried using VLOOKUP, but its not working. Is there a way to do this without macros? Or should I just give up and do the IF statements?

Comment: So is an input of exactly **3** a *"B"* or a *"C"*

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear. Its actually ranges like 102-356 and 452-556 for a product number where the input could really be anything inbetween but never the ends of the ranges. So it could be 254 but it'll never be 102 or 356. Since there are so many possible inputs, I'd like to try and avoid splitting it up for each one, but I'm definitely not opposed to a helper column. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to split the ranges or use any helper columns, you could just use a dummy lookup constructed in a similar way to your original data. For example, if your value to lookup was in cell D1 then:

`=VLOOKUP(TRUNC(D1)&"-"&TRUNC(D1+1),A1:B3,2)`

would give you the grade that you are looking for. It will construct the format of the first column using the first digit. This will only work in the example above though. You would need to adjust the `TRUNC` function if you have broader categories. For example, categories of 0-2, 2-4 etc, you could use `(TRUNC(D1/2)*2) & "=" & (TRUNC(D1/2)*2 + 2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Although normally wise to set the fourth parameter (*range_lookup*) in a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) function to FALSE (to ensure a match is returned only where the match is exact) where the *table_array* is sorted the TRUE (or default, or `1`) option may be the right choice where the *lookup_value* falls into bands:

> If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.

`Important   If range_lookup is either TRUE or is omitted, the values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP might not return the correct value.`

In this case the extremities of the bands are not allowed values, so with bands like `102-356` and `452-556` (assumed to represent `A` and `C` respectively say in A1 and A4), a helper column might be constructed from:

```
  =LEFT(A1,3)+1
```

in say B1, copied down to suit. With `A` in C1 and `C` in C5 a formula such as:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,B:C,2)
```

would return `#N/A` for `102` or less, `A` for `103` to `355` inclusive, and `C` for `453` or more. Since `556` is more than `453` but should *not* return `C` additional entries may be made to the *table_array* at the bottom, say `556` in B6 and `#N/A` in C6.

If the `B` values are given by the band `356-452` corresponding entries might be made in Rows2 and Row4 (to return `#N/A` for the band extremities that are not allowed). Alternatively, if these will never be looked up that may not be necessary though my preference would be for a *table_array* that covers all possibilities so would involve a formula that first looks for an exact match and only if that returns an error would then look for an inexact match so my *table_array* might look like this:

```
B      C  
0      #N/A
103    A
356    #N/A
357    B
452    #N/A
453    C
556    #N/A
```

and my formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,B:C,2,0),VLOOKUP(D1,B:C,2))
```